# How to memorize Indonesian words easily?

Tags: learning-methods, vocabulary, indonesian

I don't know whether it's just me, but I think that many Indonesian words look very similar. Are their any ways to memorize them (i.e tips and strategies) or tools to help me?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say a lot of words look very similar, I suspect you're mainly looking at a lot of formal words - you're naturally going to be buried in a deluge of "mengs" and "bers".
Try to learn the base-word->verb rules eg. tanya -> menanya | kerja -> mengerja and then focus on learning the much less 'samey' base words instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just like in English, memorize only the root words.  The trick is to recognize
prefix and suffix patterns, because unlike English the Indonesian language uses a lot of **prefixes** too, not just suffixes.  Some words even have both prefix and suffix (**confixes**)!  Here is a comprehensive article explaining the meaning of all common prefixes, suffixes, confixes, infixes, and combining forms: [Forming Indonesian Words & Using Indonesian Affixes](https://indodic.com/affixeng.html).

Once you learn how to recognize root words and how to modify root words, you can then focus on memorizing root words only, using common word list such as [this list of top 2000+ words](https://app.memrise.com/course/32267/2000-indonesian-words/), the book [Indonesian Vocabulary for English Speakers](https://tpbooks.com/product/usa_ind_3000/) containing 3,000 common words organized in 101 topics, and other lists you may find from [this answer](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/3806/14383).